# Update options on jquery chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I tried several things trying to make this work, I don't know if it is possible. I have the chosen plugin (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). What I want to do is the following:

- check the length of every option
- if the option is bigger than certain size
  *cut and add "..."
  *add a tooltip with the full string

The tooltip is working fine, what I don't manage is to repaint the chosen with the new (...) strings. The chosen stays with the full string.

here is my code

```
$("select").chosen().each(function () {
$(this).on("liszt:showing_dropdown", function () {

    if($(this).parent().is('.myContentClass')){
      $(this).next().find('li').each(function(){
        var size = measureText($(this).text(), 12, 'Tahoma')
        var limit = MyWidth - 50;

        if( size.width > limit){

          var tmp_str = $(this).text();
          var dot_limit = MyWidth.width() - 60;

          while(measureText(tmp_str, 12, 'Tahoma').width > dot_limit){

            tmp_str = tmp_str.substring(0, tmp_str.length - 1);
          }

          tmp_str = tmp_str + '...';
          //console.log(tmp_str) here im getting the correct string

          $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
          $(this).text(tmp_str);  // :(

          //$("select").chosen().trigger("liszt:updated"); //not working
          $('#tiptip_content').css('font-size', '13px');
          $(this).tipTip({
            maxWidth: "auto",
            defaultPosition: "left",
            fadeIn: 100,
            fadeIn: 100,
            attribute: "title"
          });
        }
        $(this).trigger("change"); //not working
      });
    }

});
```

});

Comment: Rather than doing all that work, have you considered doing this using CSS? All you would need is these CSS rules on each list item:


`overflow: hidden;`
`white-space: nowrap;`
`text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out the `div`/`span` that holds the option and add these rules to its selector:

```css
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: There is no need any longer for `-o-text-overflow` and `-ms-text-overflow`... they are synonyms for text-overflow in the supported browsers. See http://caniuse.com/text-overflow

Comment: I just copied the rules from what my browser generated. anyway, thanks. Duly noted.

Comment: Also did not see your comment on the original post. sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot dudes! growing pains, I learned something today! :)